# update ENS subdomains based on votes

Tags: addresses, ipfs, ens, eth-domain

Let's say I use ENS to assign a domain name to an IPNS address.  This address would point to a json object like the following:

```
{
  "stakeholders": ["address_of_sh_1", "address_of_sh_2", "address_of_stakeholder_3"]
}
```

Since this is an IPNS object, I could update it if I owned the server - e.g. by adding a stakeholder address to that list.  But I would like to find a way to only allow updating this list if the majority of stakeholders sign off on these changes.

Can anyone think of a way to do this?  I'm looking for the simplest possible way.